# Python Pandas dataframe subtract cumulative column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date-range

I have some data that I am importing into a Pandas dataframe. This data is "cumulative" and indexed on a time series, see below:

```
                        Raw data
2016-11-23 10:00:00     48.6 
2016-11-23 11:00:00     158.7 
2016-11-23 12:00:00     377.8 
2016-11-23 13:00:00     591.7 
2016-11-23 14:00:00     748.5 
2016-11-23 15:00:00     848.2
```

The data is updated daily, so the time series will move forward a day each day.

What I need to do is to take this dataframe and create a new column as shown below. The first row simply copies the data from the "Raw data" column. Then each subsequent row takes the data from the "Raw data" column, and subtracts the value that appeared before it, e.g. 158.7 - 48.6 = 110.1, 377.8 - 158.7 = 219.1, etc.

Does anyone know how I can achieve what is in the "Process data" column in Python/Pandas?

```
                    Raw data    Processed data
23/11/2016 10:00    48.6        48.6
23/11/2016 11:00    158.7       110.1
23/11/2016 12:00    377.8       219.1
23/11/2016 13:00    591.7       213.9
23/11/2016 14:00    748.5       156.8
23/11/2016 15:00    848.2       99.7
```

Comment: Do you need the "Processed data" column to reset to the first value each day, or should it be one long stream?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use substract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column:

Last fill `NaN` by first value in `Raw data`.

```
df['Processed data'] = df['Raw data'].sub(df['Raw data'].shift())
df['Processed data'].iloc[0] = df['Raw data'].iloc[0]
print (df)
                     Raw data  Processed data
2016-11-23 10:00:00      48.6            48.6
2016-11-23 11:00:00     158.7           110.1
2016-11-23 12:00:00     377.8           219.1
2016-11-23 13:00:00     591.7           213.9
2016-11-23 14:00:00     748.5           156.8
2016-11-23 15:00:00     848.2            99.7
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you can try this one, i found it easy :
Will create a new column with subtracted value.

```
df['processed_data'] = df['Raw_data'].diff(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of Pandas, you can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Processed data'] = df['Raw data'].diff().fillna(df['Raw data'])
print(df)

# Output
                     Raw data  Processed data
2016-11-23 10:00:00      48.6            48.6
2016-11-23 11:00:00     158.7           110.1
2016-11-23 12:00:00     377.8           219.1
2016-11-23 13:00:00     591.7           213.9
2016-11-23 14:00:00     748.5           156.8
2016-11-23 15:00:00     848.2            99.7
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) in Pandas, which has the advantage of handling cases with more columns (which are not themselves unique).

Assume you have a DataFrame like

```
timestep                fid        cumul_value
2016-11-23 10:00:00     1          48.6 
2016-11-23 11:00:00     1          158.7 
2016-11-23 12:00:00     1          377.8 
2016-11-23 13:00:00     1          591.7 
2016-11-23 14:00:00     1          748.5 
2016-11-23 15:00:00     1          848.2 
2016-11-23 10:00:00     2          88.6 
2016-11-23 11:00:00     2          758.7 
...
2016-11-23 12:00:00     5          577.8 
2016-11-23 13:00:00     5          691.7 
2016-11-23 14:00:00     5          348.5 
2016-11-23 15:00:00     5          148.2
```

where `fid` represents another parameter, over whose values `cumul_value` varies. You want to obtain a column `value` from the column `cumul_value` such that `value(fid,timestep) = cumul_value(fid,timestep) - cumul_value(fid,timestep - 1)` for each `fid`.

```
onestep = timedelta(hours=1)
df['prev_timestep'] = df['timestep'] - onestep
df_cumul = df[['id','fid','timestep','cumul_value']]
        .set_index(['timestep','fid'])
df_val = df.join(df_cumul,on=['prev_timestep','fid'],rsuffix='_prev')
df_val['value'] = df_val['cumul_value'] - df_val['cumul_value_prev']
df_val = df_val.drop(['prev_timestep','cumul_value_prev','cumul_value','id_prev'],axis=1)
```

Finish up by handling the first timestep which is likely a special case(call it `t0`)

```
df_t0 = df_cumul[df_cumul['timestep'] == t0]
df_val.loc[df_val.index.isin(df_t0.index),'value'] = df_t0['cumul_value']
```